# Specify a variable as a table name when selecting the headers of a table?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create an Excel 2010 spreadsheet with a button that will create a new sheet and copy sheet 1 to it.  I have everything figured out except that the sheets contain tables.  When the sheet is copied, the tables are renamed since you cannot have 2 tables with the same name.  The VBA scripting I have put together has a section where it needs to select the header row of the table.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim KeyCells As Range
Set KeyCells = ActiveSheet.Range("C2")
If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
       Is Nothing Then
    If ActiveSheet.Range("C2") = "KeyWord" Then
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Range("Table1[[#Headers],[Product]]").Select
        Selection.AutoFilter
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Range.AutoFilter Field:=6, Visibledropdown:=False, Criteria1:= _
        Array("All", "AS", "ASD", "ASDF"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
        ActiveSheet.Range("C3").Select
        ActiveSheet.Name = ActiveSheet.Range("C2")
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

I can get around the table renaming by using "ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)" to specify the first table on the sheet, but when specifying the range to select the headers, I cannot find a way to specify the current name of the first table on the page.

```
.Range("Table1[[#Headers],[Product]]").Select
```

I have tried to concatenate it using a variable set by specifying the first cell of the header of the table, but concatenate seems to require a "text" value before you can specify a variable.

Another thought was to store the current name of the table somewhere, change the name of the table to a static value, run the code I need to run then change the table name back to the old unique name.  I couldn't figure out a good way of doing that though.

Since the sheet has potential to be copied multiple times, and the name of the table will change each time, I need a method of specifying the table name inside the `Range()` command without setting it to a specific name.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could benefit from a bit more object-oriented programming, which would allow the script assist feature in the VBE.

Anywho, a table is a `ListObject` and has a `DataBodyRange` and also a `HeaderRowRange`.

You want to refer to the `HeaderRowRange`.

Alternatively, you can simply use the `AutoFilter` method on a table `ListObject`.

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Range.AutoFilter Field:=6, Visibledropdown:=False, Criteria1:= _
    Array("All", "AS", "ASD", "ASDF"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Comment: I guess I was just over thinking it.  The answer was in front of me the whole time.  Thanks!  :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure of what you need to achieve, but the table-name is available as:

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).DisplayName
```

which you might store in a string variable.

You can select the table, including headers, using:

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Range.Select
```

bearing in mind, however, that it is often unnecessary to select the table (with or without the header row).